# If $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$, $\sqrt{P^{n}}=P\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$, $\sqrt{P^{n}}=P\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The only exception is $n=0$ of course, :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is true. Note that $P^n\subseteq P$ and taking radicals of both sides gives the $\subseteq$ direction of the equality. So we are left to prove that $P\subseteq \sqrt{P^n}.$ Suppose $x\in P.$ Then $x^n\in P^n$ and by definition of the radical, this implies that $x\in \sqrt{P^n},$ which solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using the definition of $\sqrt{I}$ as "the intersection of prime ideals containing $I$," you immediately get that $\sqrt{P^n}\subseteq P$.

For the other containment, clearly any prime ideal containing $P^n$ must contain $P$, so the intersection of such ideals contains $P$.

Not positive what your definition is, but if you are not familiar with this one, it would be a good exercise to prove its equivalence (for commutative rings) to the other usual definition : $\sqrt{I}=\{x\in R\mid \exists n\in \Bbb N^+( x^n\in I)\}$.